# Fault Exceptions Are Not Being Recognized By Calling Service

Tags: wcf

We are throwing fault exceptions (WCF) in few scenarios. They are working in our local VMs. But when we try them on the server, service is throwing the exception but calling service is not able to recognise them and giving the below error.

> The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by
>   a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal
>   server error.

Is there any setting which disables FaultExceptions in WCF services? Any ideas from anybody?

Code added from comment:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "sample.com")] 
public interface ITransactionService 
{ 

    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(Domain.Exceptions.SimilarTransaction‌​Exception))]
    Transaction ProcessTransaction(Context context, Spec specification); 
}
```

Comment: could you share your service interface?

Comment: [ServiceContract(Namespace = "sample.com")]
 public interface ITransactionService
 {
 
 [OperationContract]
  [FaultContract(typeof(Domain.Exceptions.SimilarTransactionException))]
  Transaction ProcessTransaction(Context context, Spec specification);
 }

Comment: you better edit your question and include the code of your service interface, it will be cleaner and  easy to read.

Comment: The FaultContract are declared correctly. Is the 'SimilarTransaction‌​Exception' class in a separate assembly? Is it included with the service assemblies?

Comment: SimilarTransaction‌​Exception is in different assembly.